# Kue callback when job is completed

Tags: node.js, callback, kue

My main Node instance forks a worker process, which accepts messages over IPC (using the built-in Node `process.send()` and `process.on('message'...`) which are objects containing information about new jobs to add to [Kue](https://github.com/learnboost/kue).  It then processes those jobs.

My main Node instance calls something like this:

```
worker.send({jobType:'filesystem', operation: 'delete', path: fileDir});
```

and the worker instance does something like this:

```
jobs.create(message.jobType, message).save();

jobs.process('filesystem', function(job, done) {
    fs.delete(job.data.path, function(err) {
        done(err);
    });
});
```

and the job completes successfully.

How can I get callback-like functionality in my main Node instance when the job is completed?  How can I return some results to the main Node instance from the worker instance?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I solved this, but I'll leave the question unsolved in case anyone can improve upon my solution or provide a better one.

When you're using Kue to process jobs in a separate process, you can't simply execute a callback when the job is finished. This is an example of communication between the two processes. I would have liked to have used the id that Kue provides each job automatically (which I believe is the same id it receives in Redis) but app.js needs to know the id of the job BEFORE it gets sent to the worker so that it can match the id when it receives a message.

**app.js**

```
var child = require('child_process');
var async = require('async');

var worker = child.fork("./worker.js");

//When a message is received, search activeJobs for it, call finished callback, and delete the job
worker.on('message', function(m) {
    for(var i = 0; i < activeJobs.length; i++) {
        if(m.jobId == activeJobs[i].jobId) {
            activeJobs[i].finished(m.err, m.results);
            activeJobs.splice(i,1);
            break;
        }
    }
});

// local job system
var newJobId = 0;
var activeJobs = [];

function Job(input, callback) {
    this.jobId = newJobId;
    input.jobId = newJobId;
    newJobId++;
    activeJobs.push(this);

    worker.send(input);

    this.finished = function(err, results) {
        callback(err, results);
    }
}


var deleteIt = function(req, res) {
    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            // An *EXAMPLE* asynchronous task that is passed off to the worker to be processed
            // and requires a callback (because of async.series)
            new Job({
                jobType:'filesystem',
                title:'delete project directory',
                operation: 'delete',
                path: '/deleteMe'
            }, function(err) {
                callback(err);
            });
        },
        //Delete it from the database
        function(callback) {
            someObject.remove(function(err) {
                callback(err);
            });
        },
    ],
    function(err) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
    });
};
```

**worker.js**

```
var kue = require('kue');
var fs = require('fs-extra');

var jobs = kue.createQueue();

//Jobs that are sent arrive here
process.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.jobType) {
        var job = jobs.create(message.jobType, message).save();
    } else {
        console.error("Worker:".cyan + " [ERROR] No jobType specified, message ignored".red);
    }
});

jobs.process('filesystem', function(job, done) {

    if(job.data.operation == 'delete') {
        fs.delete(job.data.path, function(err) {
            notifyFinished(job.data.jobId, err);
            done(err);
        });
    }
});

function notifyFinished(id, error, results) {
    process.send({jobId: id, status: 'finished', error: error, results: results});
}
```

https://gist.github.com/winduptoy/4991718

Comment: Thanks - I had the same problem. Would be good if there was a simpler solution.