# execute callback after Kue job is completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, kue

I have seen questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950777/kue-callback-when-job-is-completed) but they do not answer my question.

I have a function

```
var kue = require('kue');
var jobs = kue.createQueue();

var create_job = function(data, callback){
    jobs.create('job', {
        stuff: data   
    }).save();
}
```

How can I make it so that `callback` is called when `jobs.process('job', function(job, done){ ...` is finished?

Comment: https://github.com/learnboost/kue#job-events?

Comment: yeah, but how do those get access to the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not used **kue** before, so this is going off their documentation:

```
var kue = require('kue');
var jobs = kue.createQueue();

var create_job = function(data, callback){
    var job = jobs.create('job', {
        stuff: data   
    }).save();
    job.on('complete', function(){
        callback();
    }).on('failed', function(){
      callback({error: true});
    });    
};
```

I've created/used a JavaScript closure to capture the value of the `callback` argument (by attaching the events within the scope of the `create_job` function, and it's later called when the function completes (or fails).

Comment: Awesome this worked, thanks. This may be a misunderstanding of closures on my part, but will the `job` variable be garbage collected after one of the `.on()` is triggered?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the `job` variable isn't referenced elsewhere.